# What app can I use to build some 3D geometrical shapes like circles, cylinders etc

Tags: software-recommendation, vector-drawings

Please tell me an Ubuntu 16.04 app that can build some 3D geometrical corps.

Comment: Your question is very broad. What would you like to do with these shapes once you modelled them? See also [How to run the Software Recommendation tag?](//meta.askubuntu.com/a/1873/175814)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend Blender.

Blender is a professional, free and open-source 3D computer graphics software toolset used for creating animated films, visual effects, art, 3D printed models, interactive 3D applications and video games. Blender's features include 3D modeling, UV unwrapping, texturing, raster graphics editing, rigging and skinning, fluid and smoke simulation, particle simulation, soft body simulation, sculpting, animating, match moving, camera tracking, rendering, motion graphics, video editing and compositing. It further features an integrated game engine.

Get it from
https://www.blender.org/
or

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```